# How to do sequence comparison in idiomatic Scala

Tags: scala

Input:

```
target: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

sequence1: ["b", "c"]
sequence2: ["c", "b"]
```

Desired behavior

```
sequence1 matches with target because "b", "c" matches with a sub sequence of the target

sequence2 does not match with target
```

I can write this in Python or Java with a for loop pretty easily. What is the idiomatic way to write this in scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `containsSlice()` is what you're after.

```
scala> List("a","b","c","d").containsSlice(List("b","c"))
res0: Boolean = true

scala> List("a","b","c","d").containsSlice(List("c","b"))
res1: Boolean = false
```